# Activemq postgresql logging message details and content in activemq_msgs table as JSON

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, activemq-classic

I have configured PostgreSQL connection. I want to log message details and content as JSON in `activemq_msgs`. Here is my configuration details in `activemq.xml` file:

```
    <bean id="postgres-ds" class="org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="amq"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="5432"/>
        <property name="user" value="amq_admin"/>
        <property name="password" value="1234"/>
        <property name="dataSourceName" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="initialConnections" value="15"/>
        <property name="maxConnections" value="30"/>
    </bean>

    <persistenceAdapter>
        <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data" dataSource="#postgres-ds">
           <adapter><postgresql-jdbc-adapter/></adapter>
        </jdbcPersistenceAdapter>
    </persistenceAdapter>
```

I have no changes in `log4j.properties` file right now about PostgreSQL.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who may have this same question in the future. If not, please clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in ActiveMQ 5.x to store message details in the activemq_msgs table as JSON. That data is stored as binary in either bytes or blobs. Read more about JDBC support in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-support).